Find the Hadamard factorization of $f(z)=\sinh(z)-e^z+1$

Find the Hadamard factorization of $f(z)=\sinh(z)-e^z+1$.

Here's my attempt.
First of all let us notice that $f$ is entire and that there are infinitely many zeros, namely $z_k=2k\pi i$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.
We can notice furthermore that the exponent of convergence is $\rho = 2$ (because $\sum_k \frac{1}{|2k\pi|^\rho}$ converges if $\rho\geq 2$) and the genue of the Weierstrass canonical product is $b=1$.
From these facts we can apply the Hadamard factorization theorem. My version is the following one:

Let $f\in H(\mathbb{C})$ with order of convergence $\rho_{f}\leq +\infty$. Let $z=0$ be a zero of order $m$ and let $W(z) = \prod_{j}^{+\infty} E_b(\frac{z}{\alpha_k})$ where $\{\alpha_k\}\in \mathbb{C}-{0}$ and $b$ is the genus of the Weierstrass Canonical product. Then is it possible to factorize the function as $$f(z) = z^mW(z)e^{g(z)}$$ where $g(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $\rho_{f}$.

First of all $\rho_{f}=1$ because it is a sum of functions with order of convergence $1$. Since $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$, but $f''(z)= \sinh(z)-e^z=1$, we can state that $z=0$ is a zero of order $m=2$.
Because $b=1$ and $\rho = 1$ we can factorize $f$ as
$$f(z) = z^2W(z)e^{\alpha z+\beta}$$
where $$W(z)=\prod_{k\neq 0} E_1(\frac{z}{2k\pi i})=\prod_{k\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}\left(1-\frac{z}{2k\pi i}\right)e^{\frac{z}{2k\pi i}}$$
We only need to find the costants $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
If we derive two times and we look at the point $z=0$ we find:
$$f''(0) = -1 = 2W(0)e^\beta \Rightarrow e^\beta = -\frac{1}{2}.$$
Furthermore in order to find $\alpha$ we can derive $f$ another time i.e. $$f'''(z) = -3W(z)e^{\alpha c} \left(\frac{W'(z)}{W(z)}+\alpha\right) + z(\dots) + z^2(\dots).$$
Since we will use again $z=0$ the parenthesis multiplied by $z$ and $z^2$ are useless so we can concentrate on the term $ -3W(z)e^{\alpha c} \left(\frac{W'(z)}{W(z)}+\alpha\right)$.
Since $W(z)$ is an infinite (convergent) product we can say that $$\frac{W'(z)}{W(z)} = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}-0}\left( \frac{ E'_b(\frac{z}{\alpha_k})}{ E_b(\frac{z}{\alpha_k})}\right)= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}-0}\left( \frac{ -\frac{z}{(2k\pi i)^2}}{1-\frac{z}{2k\pi i}}\right)$$
We can now use $z=0$ in the third derivative of $f$ i.e. $$f'''(0)=0=-3W(0)e^0(0+\alpha) \Rightarrow \alpha = 0$$.
Hence we can conclude that the Hadamard factorization of $f(z)= \sinh(z)-e^z+1$ is
$$f(z) = -\frac{1}{2}z^2\left(\prod_{k\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}}\left(1-\frac{z}{2k\pi i}\right)e^{\frac{z}{2k\pi i}}\right)$$
Are there any mistake? I feel like the way I computed $\alpha$ is not legit.

what does $Sh(z)$  mean?

@WillJagy It was a short form for Hyperbolic Sine, I corrected it

this is a built in operator in Latex and thus Mathjax,    use \sinh .  What is  "genue" ?

Ahlfors writes "genus"

My professor followed the Ahlfors' book, genue was just a typo

Note that $f(z)=\sinh(z)-e^z+1 = 1 - \cosh(z) =  - 2 \sinh^2(z/2) = - 2 \sin^2(i z /2)$, that simplifies things a bit.

The zeros are at $z_k = 2 k \pi i$, not at $z_k = 2 k \pi $.
